# What is the best way to access a model from a view when the model is optional?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a single view that is used by two Controller Actions.

My Controller:

```cs
AccountController {
    ...
    ActionResult LogOn() {
        return View()
    }

    [HttpPost]
    ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model) {
        return View(model)
    }
}
```

My View:

```cs
<% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UserName)) { %>
    <div class="username"><% Response.Write(Model.UserName); %></div>
<% } %>
```

Of course, the problem with the above code is that I get an error *"Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"* on the line that references **Model.UserName**.

What is the best way to my view to support both Actions? I can replace the HttpGet LogOn method with:

```cs
ActionResult LogOn() {
    result View(new LogOnModel()); 
}
```

That works, but it doesn't seem very elegant and I'm sure an empty model will break some more complex models that I will need to create later on. Is there a better way?  Thanks!

Comment: why not just use Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.UserName) ??

Comment: @samack, he doesn't want to edit the username so he doesn't need `EditorFor`, he wants to display it so he needs `DisplayFor`.

Comment: @Darin yeah I realized that and changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to my view to support both Actions?

If a view is strongly typed to a view model (which is what absolutely all your views should be) you should make sure that all your controller actions serving those views (which is pretty much all your controller actions in your application) are passing a view model to those views.

Which is pretty much bla-bla which translated into source code pretty basically means this:

```
ActionResult LogOn() {
    return View(new LogOnModel())
}
```

> That works, but it doesn't seem very elegant and I'm sure an empty
>   model will break some more complex models that I will need to create
>   later on.

That's the correct way. Don't worry. You ain't gonna break anything. It's by not providing a view model to your views that you are breaking stuff.

Also as a side note you should absolutely never use Response.Write in a view. So instead of:

```
<% Response.Write(Model.UserName); %>
```

you totally want:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UserName) %>
```

or:

```
<%: Model.UserName %>
```

but personally I prefer the `DisplayFor` helper since it will take care of any metadata.

Comment: I've used WebForms for years and knew about `<%=`, but for some reason  it wasn't working when I tried it the first time. I just reverted to a full `Response.Write()`. I'll give `<%=` another try. As for `Html.DisplayFor`, I haven't yet figured out how to manipulate the generated HTML as much as I need to.

Comment: Update: `<%=` does not work in MVC3 ASPX views. I get "_Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected_". I must use `Response.Write`.

Comment: @parleer are you using the Web Forms or the Razor view engine??

Answer (score 0):

You can either return a different view or as you have done, return a new model.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by other commenters, your Controller should support the strong-typeness of your view. But if you insist on proceeding with the anti-pattern. Replace this:

```
<% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UserName)) { %>
    <div class="username"><% Response.Write(Model.UserName); %></div>
<% } %>
```

with this:

```
<% if (Model!= null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UserName)) { %>
    <div class="username"><% Response.Write(Model.UserName); %></div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I've updated my code to be strongly typed, but I still find that I must explicitly use `<% if ... Response.Write.... %>` as opposed to `Html.DisplayFor`. Those methods just do not appear to be expressive enough to generate the HTML I want. Maybe I'm missing something.